# transfer hundreds of files specified on a list between two servers

Tags: scp, sftp, transfer

I need to download 800 files from a server to my server. These files have different names and they're in different subdirectories in the remote server, but I have their names on a list. 
How can I do this on a way that I don't have to go one by one?
I can use scp or sftp, but I don't know how to submit a list of files to be downloaded.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What OS do you have on the server you want to download the files to?

Comment: oops! sorry I forgot to mention, they're both Linux servers.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like:

```
wget http://the.source.of.it.all $(< /the/list/of/files/here)
```

or even run the whole by a script that iterates over the files reading a line from the list and asking for it.

How much do you know of shell programming? How well do you know the command line Unix utilities? Are you familiar with a scripting language, like Perl or Python?

Answer (score 0):

`sftp` has a `-b` option to read commands from a batch file. The batch file should contain a list of commands like you would type at the `sftp>` command prompt.

You could generate a batch file containing `get` commands for each file that you want to fetch, along with any other commands that you need to issue, like `lcd` or `lmkdir` to put the files in the correct local directories.